# Removing irrelevant characters from a sentence

Tags: r

I have the following sentence:

```
**I**%%AABB%&&**WANT**%%AO%**ONLY**%RA%$**THESE**
```

I would like to extract only those words that *are defined* as relevant: `I, WANT, ONLY, THESE, WORDS, NEXT, STEP`. All other characters (numeric, alpha, special) should be removed from the sentence.

In this case, the resulting sentence would be:

```
I WANT ONLY THESE.
```

I have thousands of lines like these and each has its own set of characters between the useful words. Is there an efficient way to get rid of these in R?

Comment: Yes....I have a list of words that are relevant...I want everything else to be removed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string <- "**I**%%AABB%&&**WANT**%%AO%**ONLY**%RA%$**THESE**"
regmatches(string, gregexpr("I|WANT|ONLY|THESE|WORDS|NEXT|STEP", 
                            string))

[[1]]
[1] "I"     "WANT"  "ONLY"  "THESE"
```

EDIT: If you want to then convert back to a sentence, say I store the matches in an object called `matches`:

```
sentencify <- function(sentence){
  paste0(paste(sentence, collapse=" "), ".")
}

lapply(matched, sentencify)

[[1]]
[1] "I WANT ONLY THESE."
```

Comment: In general, you can create the pattern with `paste(., sep="|")`.

Comment: Very nice. I'm not very familiar with `regmatches`. +1

Comment: Is `perl=TRUE` necessary here? In other words, what's the use of it here?

Comment: @Arun Sorry, that's a relic from a previous attempt. I'll remove it.

Comment: @AnandaMahto `regmatches` is the function that really makes `gregexpr` usable.

Comment: Thank you so much, sebastian-c. Is there a way to make it return a sentence instead of a bag of words list?

Comment: @Ravi if this helped you, then you *may* want to consider pressing the green tick next to the answer (but you are certainly **not** obliged to) indicating that this satisfactorily answered your question and then this question can be removed from the unanswered questions stack. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach, assuming you have a list to check against:

```
> mystring2 <- "**I**%%AABB%&&**WANT**%%AO%**ONLY**%RA%$**THESE**"
> mystring2
[1] "**I**%%AABB%&&**WANT**%%AO%**ONLY**%RA%$**THESE**"
> temp <- strsplit(mystring2, "[^a-zA-Z]")[[1]]
> myWords <- c("I", "WANT", "ONLY", "THESE", "WORDS", "NEXT", "STEP")
> temp[temp %in% myWords]
[1] "I"     "WANT"  "ONLY"  "THESE"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a list of relevant words, let `hunspell` do it automatically :)

```
> system(paste('echo "', gsub('\\W', ' ', '**I**%%AABB%&&**WANT**%%AO%**ONLY**%RA%$**THESE**'), '" | hunspell -G -d en_US'))
I
WANT
ONLY
RA
THESE
```